# How to expand the function of seq() to list or dataframe?

Tags: r

So now I have a list look like this:

```
$a
[1] 2

$b
[1] 5

$c
[1] 3
```

Just wonder if there's a way to make them become:

```
$a
[1] 1 2

$b
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

$c
[1] 1 2 3
```

Thank you very much for your answer!!

Comment: `lapply(myList, seq)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `seq`

```
lapply(lst1, seq)
```